# UITableViewCell width always returns 320

Tags: ios

Cell width always return 320, once reload the table then it returns proper cell width based on device(iphone/ipad).Below is the code

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

NSString *reuseIdentifier = @"testCell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];

if(cell == nil)

 {
     cell = [[UITableViewCellalloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefaultreuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];

 }    

cell.textLabel.text = @"test";

return cell;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

probably it's because in first time your cell will be created via

```
[[UITableViewCellalloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefaultreuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
```

but after reload table your cell will be reused via

```
[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:reuseIdentifier]
```

with "old" sizes.

To avoid this, use correct cell identifier in Interface builder, in this case you can even remove creating cell code

```
[[UITableViewCellalloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefaultreuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier]
```

cell will be always generated from interface